# Ant: concat the output of an executable to some other files without creating a temporary file?

Tags: ant

See the example below.

```
<concat destfile="dest-file">
    <fileset dir="dir1" />
    <!-- how to append the output of the executable below without creating a temporary file for that output? -->
    <apply executable="command1">...</apply>
</concat>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`apply`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) and [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) tasks support [`redirector`s](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/redirector.html) so you can do something like:

```
<apply executable="command1" >
    <redirector append="true" output="file.log" />
</apply>
```